# Derby database in NetBeans localhost doesnot appear

Tags: database, netbeans, connection, derby, javadb

when i change the proprties of Java DB , the local host folder does appear but then i delete it for some resons , now when i try to get it again it is not work, what to do?
1- [image: here the proprties]
2- [image: here is after click on iok, no localholst!]